# ajax jquery an empty error callback on success server operation

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, callback

I make an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Login.aspx/AuthenticateRegularUser',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{ "emailAddress": "' + emailAddress + '","password": "' + password + '","verificationCode": "' + verificationCode + '" }',
    success: function(Result) {
        if (Result != "") {
            var ClientResponse = JSON.parse(Result.d);
            if (ClientResponse.Success) {
        //DO SUCCESS
            }

            else {
        //DO FAIL
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //DO ERROR
    }
});
```

Most of the times everything is working fine, and I get success callback.
But one of my clients has a problem that sometimes the operation completed successfully on the server, but I get an error callback with an empty error.
jqXHR is empty, textStatus = "" and null errorThrown.

any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the different type of browser?? Could be an IE related issue. Maybe ask the client to use firefox instead.

Could be IE interpret javascript differently to firefox, I had similar sort of issue before at work. Microsoft always try to have its own standard for javascript, html, css. Also check data: '{ "emailAddress": "' + emailAddress + there are seems to have too many Quotation mark.

Thanks

Comment: Possible, but do you have any idea why or what it means?

Comment: Could be IE interpret javascript differently to firefox, see my updated answer.

Comment: and it makes sense that most of the time it works that way (like 8 calls out of 10) but only a few times fail?

Comment: Tell your client to try firefox latest version, it be the answer for your problem.

Comment: I can't :) we support all browser types.

Comment: IE 11 :) but I noticed I get the error before I get any response from the server! I opened a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515201/jquery-ajax-hits-error-callback-before-getting-response-from-the-server-ie11?noredirect=1#comment30675011_20515201

Comment: Try to enable the internet explorer compatibility mode

Answer (score 1):

Try, need to  remove `'` infront of `data` and syntax like as mentioned below

```
 data: { "emailAddress": emailAddress, "password": password, "verificationCode": verificationCode },
```

instead of

```
  data: '{ "emailAddress": "' + emailAddress + '","password": "' + password + '","verificationCode": "' + verificationCode + '" }',
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, I will try, but can you tell me why do you think it can be a problem?